# jquery equivalent for list.detect in prototype

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

What would be the jquery equivalent for list.detect in prototype?

Answer (score 3):

Returns the index of the first element with "value":

```
jQuery.inArray(value, array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Prototype's detect takes an iterator and finds the first element for which the iterator returns true. jQuery's inArray does not cover this functionality. jQuery's grep() is a better match IMO.